# JavaScript not replacing all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying replace the index of form elements. I have the following

```
    var test = "<input name='[1].Id' value='598' type='hidden' /><input name='[1].OrderItemId' value='867' type='hidden' />";
    alert(test.replace('[1]', '[2]'));
```

I'm getting curious results. The first hidden field is replaced by the second is ignored

ie my response is something like this:

```
"<input name='[1].Id' value='598' type='hidden' /><input name='[2].OrderItemId' value='867' type='hidden' />"
```

EDIT:

OK, thanks these methods worked on my simple example. However in reality my string is a bit more complex. Here is the contents of "var lastRow "

```
<td>

                 <a class="deleteAddress" href="#">
                 <img alt="remove" src="/images/icons/delete_button.gif">
                 </a></td>
                <td class="p-5" width="100">
                   <input name="[1].Id" value="612" type="hidden">
                   <input name="[1].OrderItemId" value="868" type="hidden">
                   <input class="itemAddressQuantity" name="[1].Quantity" value="" type="text">

                </td>
               <td class="p-5" width="100">
               <select name="[1].AddressId"><option value="2">address1</option></select>                            
                </td>
```

and here is the js function

```
    $('#addNewAddress').click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var length = $('.table-item-address tbody').find('tr').length;
       var previousLength = length - 1;
        var previousIndex = "/\[" + previousLength + "\]/g";
        var currentIndex = "[" + length + "]";
        var lastRow = $('.table-item-address tbody tr').last();
alert(lastRow.html()); // html is shown above
        var newRow = lastRow.html().replace(previousIndex, currentIndex);
        $('.table-item-address tr').last().after('<tr>' + newRow + '</tr>');
        AdjustValues();
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, passing a string as the first parameter to `replace()` will only replace the first occurrence. You need to use a regex, with the global flag:

```
test.replace(/\[1\]/g, '[2]');
```

The extra backslashes (`\`) escape the brackets (`[` and `]`).

---

**Edit:** responding to the OP's edit, if you want to dynamically build a regex, you can't use a regex literal - that's the thing delimited by forward slashes (`/`), *not* quotes (`"`) as in your edit. You're passing a string into `replace()`, I'm passing in a regex literal. Use the [JavaScript `RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/core_javascript_1.5_guide/regular_expressions) to fix yours:

```
// The first argument is the regex, the second is a string of flags.
var previousIndex = new RegExp("\\[" + previousLength + "\\]", "g");

// Then, it's exactly the same as before.
// The second argument to replace is still a string.
var newRow = lastRow.html().replace(previousIndex, currentIndex);
```

**Note the difference in character escaping.**

Comment: thanks, this work on my example. So  yes your rightly deserve the correct answer. tho hope you could have a quick look at the edit.

Comment: Have a look at my edits. There's a cleaner way to do it - working on that now.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I forgot that JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind (and [faking it is a major headache](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript))!

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Check the 3rd sample where they talk about global replace

Answer (score 0):

change the replace to this `replace(/[1]/g, '[2]');`
This does a global replace.  However I'm not sure [] and . are legal characters for ids/names.